# Swift "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC-I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)" when using keyBoardWillShow

Tags: xcode, parsing, swift, error-handling, mkmapview

I am trying to let a user click on a cell in a tale view and it brings them to the DetailViewController.  The only problem is that each time I try to do this the error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC-I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)" comes up.

This is in the DetailViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyBoardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    //FIRST ERROR HERE
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyBoardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    //SECOND ERROR HERE

    /* Setup the contentInsets */
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero


    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None
    /* Make sure the content doesn't go below tabbar/navbar */
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true

    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false




    /* Setup Map */
    let geo = party?.objectForKey("location") as PFGeoPoint
    //THIRD ERROR HERE
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: geo.latitude, longitude: geo.longitude)
    let reg = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, 1500, 1500)
    self.mapView.setRegion(reg, animated: true)
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true



    if(party?.objectForKey("comments") != nil) {
        comments = party?.objectForKey("comments") as? [String]
    }
    println(party)
    println(party?.objectForKey("Name"))
    self.nameLabel.text = party?.objectForKey("Name") as? String



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   }
```

The other issue is that even after I put // in front of keyBoardWillShow the same error happens for keyBoardWillHide.  And if I cover that I get once again the same error trying to setup a map view.  As you can probably see, I am just getting into swift, xcode, and Parse and I have no idea what I really and doing.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "the error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC-I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)" comes up" But on which line, exactly?

Comment: Oh, I thought I marked it.  The first error is right under "NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyBoardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)"

Comment: I pasted your code into an app and it compiles fine. Of course if the keyboard actually appears we will crash, but I don't crash just because the table view controller loads.

Comment: Wait, why would it crash when the keyboard appears?

Comment: Could it be that Parse is messing this up somehow? I've never used it.

Comment: It would crash because I don't have a function called `keyBoardWillShow` :) But I don't need one just to test that your code compiles and runs.

Comment: The error doesn't really come up until I compile and run.  When I am just editing there is no error.  I don't think that Parse should be causing this problem, but I don't really know.  I'm new to Parse.  I'm following this tutorial:  http://shrikar.com/blog/2015/01/08/using-uitableview-and-footerview-to-implement-commenting-system-building-yik-yak-clone-part-3/

Comment: Right, I'm just saying I can compile and run fine. There's nothing overtly wrong with your notification center calls.

Comment: Ok.  I can't seems to figure out what's going on.  Thanks anyway

Comment: May I humbly suggest that if you're just starting out, you not use Parse or _any_ third-party code? Life is hard enough without putting some massive and possibly untrustworthy framework between you and the already massive framework that is Cocoa. And people will be able to help you much more if you have no dependencies that others do not have.

Comment: Right now it is my goal to learn or try out Parse.  I guess so far it ain't doing to well